# Why is this function not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus

I was brushing up on some calculus and I was thinking about the following function:

> Let$$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{yx^{6} +y^{3}+x^{3}y}{x^{6}+y^{2}} & \text{for $(x,y)$ $\neq (0,0)$,} \\
> 0 & \text{for  $(x,y)$ $=$ $(0,0)$. }  \\
> \end{cases}$$The function $f$ is continuous over the entire real line and is differentiable everywhere except at $x=0$.

For some arbitrary nonzero $\xi=(u,v)$, I was able to compute the directional derivative ${\xi}f(0,0)=\frac{1}{h}f(hu,hv)=v$. In particular for $\xi=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}=(1,0)$, we have $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(0,0)=0$ and for $\xi=\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}=(0,1)$, we have that $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(0,0)=1$. From here we see that  partial derivative depends linearly on the vector we differentiate on meaning $(t{\xi}))f(0,0)=(tu,tv)f(0,0)=tv=t({\xi}f(0,0))$.

**This function is not differentiable at the origin, in fact it is not even continuous at the origin. I was having trouble seeing exactly why**. I've forgotten lots of calculus, but I was wondering if the fact that $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(0,0)=1$ while $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(0,0)=0$ implies discontinuity at $(0,0)$.

Also as a side note, there is the big theorem in differential calculus which says if all the directional derivatives ${\xi}f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous at a point $p$, then $f$ is differentiable at the point $p$. **I'm confused as to how the partial derivatives above are not continuous.**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847065/prove-that-fx-y-fracyx6y3x3yx6y2-is-not-differentiable-at-the-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** consider approaching the origin along the path $(x,x^3)$

Comment: The path $(x,x)$ will also be revealing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I posted an answer below just for practice that incorporates the hint. Thanks again.

Comment: @user135520 You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

We have that differentiability implies continuity, therefore if $f$ is differentiable at the origin then it will be continuous at the origin. Which means we must have

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=(0,0)$

We consider approaching the origin along the path $(x,x^{3})$ where

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{yx^{6} +y^{3}+x^{3}y}{x^{6}+y^{2}}$ becomes

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x^{9}+x^{6}}{x^{6}}=\frac{1}{2}$

This implies that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) \neq  (0,0)$ which implies that $f$ is not continuous.